# Supervisor is not started into my docker container (Laravel project)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile, supervisord

Supervisor is not started into my container and i am not able to run my `php artisan queue:work` command for my laravel project.

Extract from my Dockerfile

```
# Add worker to supervisor config file
COPY laravel-worker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Here is the laravel-worker.conf:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
command=php /var/www/test/current/artisan queue:work --tries=3
user=myuser
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)d
directory=/var/www/test/current
stdout_logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

When i go into the container, the supervisor service is not started:

```
root@e7227ef40f63:/# service supervisor status
supervisord is  not running.
```

And process are following:

```
root@e7227ef40f63:/# ps -aux | grep supervisor
root         1  0.0  0.0   4328   652 ?        Ss   18:21   0:00 /bin/sh -c service ssh restart && service apache2 restart && service cron start && bash /usr/bin/supervisord
root       365  0.0  0.0  55808 10632 ?        Ss   18:25   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root       380  0.0  0.0  11120   712 ?        S+   18:27   0:00 grep supervisor
```

**UPDATE**

I edited my DockerFile and put this line:

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && service apache2 restart && service cron start && /usr/bin/supervisord && bash
```

The service is now well started when the container starts :

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.0   4328   652 ?        Ss   05:20   0:00 /bin/sh -c service ssh restart && service apache2 restart && service cron start && /usr/bin/supervisord && bash
root        25  0.0  0.0  55176  1140 ?        Ss   05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root        43  0.1  0.0 406408 25504 ?        Ss   05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data    46  0.0  0.0 406440  8416 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data    47  0.0  0.0 406440  8416 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data    48  0.0  0.0 406440  8416 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data    49  0.0  0.0 406440  8416 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data    50  0.0  0.0 406440  8416 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root        59  0.0  0.0  17484   636 ?        Ss   05:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root        63  0.2  0.0  56012 10788 ?        Ss   05:20   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
root        64  0.0  0.0  20032  1280 ?        S    05:20   0:00 bash
root        89  0.1  0.0  20240  1996 ?        Ss   05:20   0:00 bash
root       112  0.0  0.0  17492  1168 ?        R+   05:21   0:00 ps -aux
```

But it seams that supervisor doesn't start my config file because i don't see the 8 processes that should be run..

Answer (score 0):

This is the bad part:

```
&& bash /usr/bin/supervisord
```

`supervisord` is not a bash script. Execute it as is: `&& /usr/bin/supervisord`.

**However**, I recommend you to completely avoid using `service` in a container. In general, running more than one process into a container is considered an [antipattern](http://blog.arungupta.me/docker-container-anti-patterns/), but if you really need it, better only use `supervisor` . Create a `.conf` file for each process (cron, sshd, etc) and only run supervosord as is in your `CMD`.

Comment: Do `supervisorctl status`, and `supervisorctl tail laravel-worker`